# How to remove the first element of a linked list?

Tags: list, delphi, linked-list, pascal

This procedure `Supprimerpremier` should delete the first element of the linked list by moving the head pointer to the 2nd element and then disposing the first element it doesn't seem to work.

I don't know why it's not working; when I display the list with the procedure it  the list still has 3 elements.

Thanks in advance =)

```
Program TP1;

Uses crt ;

Type  
      T = ^TT;
      TT = Record    //declaring my list 
        s: String;
        n: Integer;
        nxt: T;
      End;
    Var
      x,p : T ;
    
Procedure Supprimerpremier (L : T); // procedure to delete the first element of my list 
    Var
      x: T;
         iptr: ^integer;
       y: ^word;
    Begin
    x:=L;
    L:=L^.nxt;
    Dispose(x);
    End;

Procedure Afficher (L :T);  //prints the list 
Var
  x: T;
Begin
  x := L;
  While ( x^.nxt<> Nil ) Do //
    Begin
      Writeln;
      Writeln;
      Writeln(x^.s);
      Writeln(x^.n);
      x := x^.nxt;
    End;
  Writeln;
  Writeln;
  Writeln(x^.s);
  Writeln(x^.n);
End;
//

Begin 
           new(p);
              p^.n := 1111;
              p^.s := 'iam the first element';
              new(p^.nxt);
              p^.nxt^.n := 222;
              p^.nxt^.s := 'iam the second element';
              new(p^.nxt^.nxt);
              p^.nxt^.nxt^.n := 778; 
              p^.nxt^.nxt^.s := 'iam the third element ';
              p^.nxt^.nxt^.nxt := Nil;

    Supprimerpremier (p); //
    Afficher (p); 
end;
```

Comment: Please write a procedure that adds a value to the list's tail. It hurts my eyes to see p^.nxt^.nxt^.n = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `L` parameter **by value**, so the procedure receives a *copy* of whatever variable the caller passes in (ie, `p`). Any modification the procedure makes to the value of `L` (ie, the `L:=L^.nxt;` statement) will not be reflected back to the caller's variable.

You need to pass the `L` parameter by **var reference** instead, eg:

`Procedure Supprimerpremier (var L : T);`

Comment: See also [Pass by reference in Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604999/) and [variable parameter](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Variable_parameter).